How to make the Perl gather construct work
I want to use the gather command several times on one perl array. The first time it works, but the very same command fails on the second attempt.
I have a string of automatic station data for specific time intervals. The data is so awkwardly written that one time interval string contains 8 stations of data. The first 3 stations have 13 string of data, the next 4 have 35 strings and the last one has 13, as below
2024-08-02  00:00:00;15.0;50.6;2.9;7.6;38;29;-2.7;846.9;;28.0;0;93;12.7;14.4;47.6;3.8;8.0;86;101;-2.5;833.8;;30.6;0;56;12.9;12.9;60.7;3.2;6.7;45;56;-0.7;843.6;;82.2;0;76;12.8;14.0;53.2;2.2;3.7;50;41;-1.2;841.9;;19.2;0;63;12.9;10.0;8.8;8.5;7.5;7.7;7.2;8.1;8.3;8.8;8.4;9.3;9.7;1.9;4.2;5.7;4.5;5.8;7.4;7.1;7.1;14.1;7.9;23.7;26.3;12.7;61.0;1.9;4.2;22;51;-1.2;839.5;;45.2;0;66;12.9;8.4;7.9;7.6;6.8;6.8;7.2;7.2;7.5;7.6;8.3;8.6;8.7;2.2;16.3;13.2;9.0;28.0;22.4;27.2;34.3;41.0;39.4;47.4;48.3;13.5;50.4;2.6;5.0;44;60;-2.0;827.0;;29.6;1;53;13.0;10.0;9.3;8.7;7.8;7.0;7.3;7.6;8.2;8.3;9.3;9.8;10.0;0.2;5.8;11.4;17.7;23.5;22.3;18.5;11.4;5.5;9.5;20.9;19.6;14.2;51.3;1.7;5.2;40;20;-0.8;844.3;;42.4;0;57;12.9;8.3;8.3;8.7;7.9;7.8;8.2;9.7;9.8;9.9;10.4;10.5;10.4;0.3;10.9;3.6;2.7;0.8;15.6;33.9;33.5;33.4;37.6;36.8;35.2;12.4;52.9;;;;;-0.6;813.1;;0.0;0;46;13.0
2024-08-02 00:10:00;15.0;50.8;2.7;7.4;32;76;-0.8;847.1;;28.0;0;89;12.7;14.4;47.9;5.1;10.0;86;85;-1.4;833.8;;30.6;0;53;12.9;12.7;61.4;2.8;6.2;37;59;-1.3;843.5;;82.2;0;72;12.8;14.3;51.7;2.5;5.8;61;360;-0.5;841.6;;19.2;0;69;12.9;10.0;8.8;8.5;7.4;7.7;7.2;8.1;8.2;8.8;8.4;9.3;9.6;1.9;4.2;5.7;4.5;5.9;7.4;7.1;7.1;14.1;7.9;23.7;26.3;12.6;62.1;1.5;3.1;13;25;-0.9;839.5;;45.2;0;56;12.9;8.3;7.9;7.6;6.8;6.8;7.2;7.2;7.5;7.6;8.3;8.6;8.7;2.2;16.3;13.2;9.0;28.0;22.4;27.2;34.3;41.0;39.4;47.4;48.3;13.3;51.4;2.9;5.9;40;41;-1.3;827.0;;29.6;1;69;12.9;9.8;9.3;8.7;7.8;7.0;7.3;7.5;8.2;8.3;9.3;9.8;9.9;0.2;5.8;11.4;17.7;23.5;22.3;18.5;11.4;5.5;9.5;20.9;19.6;14.0;51.8;0.9;2.0;343;322;-0.7;844.3;;42.4;0;65;12.9;8.2;8.3;8.7;7.9;7.8;8.2;9.7;9.8;9.9;10.3;10.5;10.4;0.3;10.9;3.6;2.7;0.8;15.6;33.9;33.6;33.4;37.7;36.8;35.2;12.4;52.7;;;;;-0.8;812.8;;0.0;0;45;13.0
2024-08-02 00:20:00;15.0;51.6;2.3;6.2;46;65;-3.0;847.0;;28.0;0;103;12.7;13.9;49.1;4.4;7.5;79;89;-1.3;833.8;;30.6;0;54;12.9;12.7;62.7;3.1;6.3;45;6;-0.7;843.5;;82.2;0;69;12.8;14.4;50.6;2.9;5.7;25;14;-0.3;841.9;;19.2;0;56;12.9;10.0;8.8;8.5;7.5;7.7;7.2;8.1;8.3;8.8;8.4;9.2;9.7;1.9;4.2;5.7;4.5;5.9;7.4;7.1;7.1;14.1;7.9;23.7;26.3;12.4;63.1;2.0;4.3;28;49;-0.8;839.4;;45.2;0;64;12.9;8.3;7.9;7.6;6.8;6.8;7.2;7.2;7.5;7.6;8.3;8.6;8.7;2.2;16.3;13.2;9.0;28.0;22.4;27.2;34.3;41.0;39.4;47.4;48.3;13.5;51.4;4.1;6.9;32;42;-0.5;827.0;;29.6;0;69;12.9;9.8;9.3;8.7;7.8;7.0;7.3;7.5;8.2;8.3;9.2;9.8;10.0;0.2;5.7;11.4;17.7;23.5;22.3;18.5;11.4;5.5;9.5;20.9;19.6;13.8;55.6;2.2;5.1;303;317;-2.8;844.6;;42.4;0;71;12.9;8.3;8.3;8.7;7.9;7.8;8.2;9.7;9.8;9.9;10.4;10.5;10.4;0.3;10.9;3.6;2.7;0.8;15.6;33.9;33.5;33.4;37.7;36.8;35.2;12.1;53.6;;;;;-1.0;812.6;;0.0;0;57;12.9

My equally clumsy code is given below
The data is comma delimited and sometimes zero values are represented as ;;, hence I have to some cleaning up.
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use Tie::File;
use List::Gather;
my @list_stns=("stn1","stn2","stn3","stn4","stn5","stn6","stn7","stn8");
my $list_stns;

my $datestr=qr{\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}};
my $timestr=qr{\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}};
my $file="data.csv";
my $nfile="newfile.txt";

my @array;
my $line; 
my $array;
my @array1;
my $array1;
my @first;
my @second;
my @third;

tie @array, 'Tie::File', $file, mode => O_RDWR;
my $x = shift @array;

for(@array){
s/;;;;;/;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;/g;
s/;;/;0.0;/g; 
s/;/ /g;
}

open (my $INFILE, "> ddata.csv") or die "open 'ddata.csv': failed $! ($^E)";
for (my$kk=0; $kk < @array; ++$kk){
 print $INFILE "$array[$kk]\n";
}
close($INFILE);

my $yr;
my $mn;
my $dy;
my $hr;
my $mi;

open (my $OUTFILE, "< ddata.csv") or die "open 'data.csv': failed $! ($^E)";
for (my $kk=0; $kk < @array; ++$kk){
 $array1[$kk]=<$OUTFILE>;
 $line=$array1[$kk];
my($datestr, $timestr, $all_fields)=split(' ', $line, 3);

$yr=substr($datestr, 0, 4);
$mn=substr($datestr, 5, 2);
$dy=substr($datestr, 8, 2);
$hr=substr($timestr, 0, 2);
$mi=substr($timestr, 3, 2);

my(@all_fields)=split(' ', $all_fields);
@first = gather{for(@all_fields){take $_ if gathered < 13}};
open (my $AWSF, "> $list_stns[0]") or die "open '$list_stns[0]': failed $! ($^E)";
print $AWSF "Year Mon Day Hr Mn Temp  Humd  Wspd  Wdir Press  Rain\n";

$_ = sprintf "%5.1f", $_ foreach @first;
print $AWSF "$list_stns[0]\n";
print $AWSF "$yr  $mn  $dy $hr $mi", join(" ", ($first[0],$first[1],$first[2],$first[4],$first[7],$first[8])),"\n";
close($AWSF);

@second = gather { for ( @all_fields) { take $_ if (gathered >= 13) && (gathered < 26)}};
print "@all_fields\n";
print "@second\n"; #this prints a blank line
exit;
open ($AWSF, "> $list_stns[1]") or die "open '$list_stns[1]': failed $! ($^E)";
print $AWSF "Year Mon Day Hr Mn Temp  Humd  Wspd  Wdir Press  Rain\n";

$_ = sprintf "%5.1f", $_ foreach @second;
print $AWSF "$list_stns[1]\n";
print $AWSF "$yr  $mn  $dy $hr $mi", join(" ", ($second[0],$second[1],$second[2],$second[4],$second[7],$second[8])),"\n";
close($AWSF);
}

I will be appreciate any assistance.

You do know that when you tie a file with Tie::File, and you shift elements off its array, you are directly editing the original file? Removing the first line of the file.

You know that you have an exit in the middle of the for loop? This means only the first line of your @array file is ever parsed. Also, what is your question?

Don't use Tie::File. It's a really bad solution in the best of cases, and completely useless here.

The title of your question is about List::Gather. If that's true, you have much unnecessary detail. Please trim down the question to its essentials if so. Either way, please clarify what you are asking.

Yes the intention was to remove the first line. The exit statements are usued regularly to test the code up to the point they occur. I will resolve my problem using Fortran, it is will be more straight forward. Thank you every body for you time.

@ZiloreMumba With Tie::File, each time you run the script you will remove the first line, until your file is empty. I hope you had backup of your data. I don't understand why you used it, though, since you already show you know how to open a file and read and write from it. Your code is not too bad, try to encapsulate more, don't try to make a do-it-all-at-once machine. Divide your code into parsing first, then manipulation, then presentation. And don't put all the variables in a huge list at the top. Put them where they are used, in the smallest scope possible.


@second = gather { for ( @all_fields) { take $_ if (gathered >= 13) && (gathered < 26)}};

Here, take $_ will never be executed since gathered is 0 in the beginning. Here is an example of how you could do this without using List::Gather:
use v5.38;
use Object::Pad;
use experimental qw(declared_refs refaliasing);

{
    my $csv_file = 'data.csv';
    my @list_stns = qw(stn1 stn2 stn3 stn4 stn5 stn6 stn7 stn8);
    my $header = "Year Mon Day Hr Mn Temp  Humd  Wspd  Wdir Press  Rain";
    my $self = Main->new(csv_file => $csv_file);
    my \@array = $self->read_file();
    for my $line (@array) {
        my($datestr, $timestr, $all_fields) = split ' ', $line, 3;
        $datestr = $self->parse_date($datestr, $timestr);
        my \@first = $self->gather_fields($all_fields, 0, 13);
        $self->write_to_file($list_stns[0], $header, $datestr, \@first);
        my \@second = $self->gather_fields($all_fields, 13, 26);
        $self->write_to_file($list_stns[1], $header, $datestr, \@second);
        exit;
    }
}

class Main;
field $csv_file :param :reader;

method gather_fields($all_fields, $start, $end) {
    my @all_fields = split ' ', $all_fields;
    @all_fields = @all_fields[$start..$end];
    return \@all_fields;
}

method parse_date($datestr, $timestr) {
    my $yr = substr($datestr, 0, 4);
    my $mn = substr($datestr, 5, 2);
    my $dy = substr($datestr, 8, 2);
    my $hr = substr($timestr, 0, 2);
    my $mi =substr($timestr, 3, 2);
    return "$yr  $mn  $dy $hr $mi";
}

method read_file() {
    my $fn = $self->csv_file;
    my @array;
    open (my $fh, "<", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while (<$fh>) {
        s/;;;;;/;0.0;0.0;0.0;0.0;/g;
        s/;;/;0.0;/g; 
        s/;/ /g;
        push @array, $_;
    }
    return \@array;
}

method write_to_file($stn, $header, $datestr, $fields) {
    my $fn = $stn;
    open (my $fh, ">", $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh "$header\n";
    my @fmt_fields = map {sprintf "%5.1f", $_} @$fields;
    print $fh "$stn\n";
    print $fh "$datestr ", join(" ", @fmt_fields), "\n";
    close($fh);
}


Thanks @Håkon Hægland, I will give this a try and let you know how it goes.

once again thanks very much. The script you provided works perfectly and does exactly what I wanted. The only small adjustments I have to make is that it prints the station name after the header. I want it the other way round. I really appreciate your help, thank you very much.

there is no further question at all. in fact I have removed writing the station name and header from the subroutine. These are done outside the main script and in write_to_file sub the file is opened for appending because it already has a station name and header. Thanks very much indeed.
